# D3 visualization filter - wrong x and y coordinates

Tags: d3.js

i'm making a d3 visualization for a school project.. but i'm stuck! Everything works.. all the dots are on the right place but when i trying to filter stuff it breaks..

I've a data_sheet that looks like this (it's much longer than the picture) http://postimg.org/image/68jzjj2br/

I wrote this code to show all the data in a d3 visualization

```
var all_data;
    var display_data;
    var svg;
    var positief = "positief";
    var neutraal = "neutraal";
    var negatief = "negatief";

    d3.csv("data/oh_data.csv", function(dataset){
      all_data = dataset;
      display_data = all_data;
      drawGraphic();
    });

    function drawGraphic(){
      svg = d3.select("#svg-3");
      svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(display_data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cy", function(d){
          return (d["y"]);
        })
        .attr("cx", function(d){
          return (d["x"]);
        })

        svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(display_data)
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("r", 5)

        .style("fill",function(d){
          if(d["waarde"] == positief){
            return "green";
          }else if(d["waarde"] == neutraal){
            return "yellow";
          }else{
            return "red";
          }
        })

    }//Einde drawGraphic
```

This works and looks like this http://postimg.org/image/ofxpeoiet/

But now the problem comes.. i want to filter Let's say i only want to see the circles of Romeo I wrote this code

```
function filterRomeo(){
      clearGraphic();

      display_data = new Array();
      for(i=0; i<all_data.length; i++){
        if(all_data[i]["persoon"] == "Romeo"){
          display_data.push(all_data[i]);
        }
      }
      setTimeout("drawGraphic()",500);
    }

    function clearGraphic(){
      svg.selectAll("circle")
        .transition()
        .duration("1000")
        .attr("r", 0);

    }
```

What happens looks like this http://postimg.org/image/3vkvuuydj

It gets everything of Romeo but places it at te wrong x and y coordinates. For example.. i finds the first Romeo Match at line 8 but places it at the coordinates of line 2.. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no key for your data binding - .data(display_data) is better done as .data(displayData, function(d) { d.someIdOrOther; }) - where someIdOrOther is a property holding a unique key for each datum in your dataset

Otherwise when you reattach data as you do after FilterRomeo() it will attach that new data to the first 'n' (where n is the size of the filtered dataset) elements it encounters, whether they are the ones relevant to Romeo or not

Comment: i'm not fully understandig this.. can you give me some example code? :D

Comment: D3's author probably explains it better than I could --> http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#key

The basic gotcha is that without a key function, data will join to the elements in dom occurence order with no regard for the data contents, which is what's happening in your example when you filter your original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is related to the fact, that you are using the enter() selection in your drawGraphic() function.

The moment you initally render the graphic, you bind data to the single nodes.

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(display_data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
```

I assume you are trying to unbind the data by the "clearGraphic" function. However all you are doing is reducing their radius to 0. The nodes still exist and the data is still bound to them.

You are trying to bind new data the nodes by updating display_data array. However you are running simply the drawGraphic function again. By using again the enter() selection d3 will skip those nodes, that have already data assigned to them. Thats at least my understanding.

Here is a good source for understanding selections 
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/